# Is there some way to use a folder seletor (FolderBrowserDialog) in WPF Core?

Tags: wpf, .net-core

I would like to have a dialog to select a folder in a WPF Core application, but I am not able to find the way.

In a WPF net framework application, I could use FolderBrowserDialog of System.Windows.Forms.

I have read this thread: [OpenFileDialog on .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795009/openfiledialog-on-net-core)

But for me it is not clear how to use the solution of the mm8 user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't provide a folder selector in FolderBrowserDialog by default, which I found surprising. You can download the Windows API Code Pack  by going to your Nuget Package Manager and typing in the following commands:

```
Install-Package WindowsAPICodePack-Core
Install-Package WindowsAPICodePack-ExtendedLinguisticServices
Install-Package WindowsAPICodePack-Sensors
Install-Package WindowsAPICodePack-Shell
Install-Package WindowsAPICodePack-ShellExtensions
```

Then add references to `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll` and `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll`. Sample code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;

var dlg = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
dlg.Title = "My Title";
dlg.IsFolderPicker = true;
dlg.InitialDirectory = currentDirectory;

dlg.AddToMostRecentlyUsedList = false;
dlg.AllowNonFileSystemItems = false;
dlg.DefaultDirectory = currentDirectory;
dlg.EnsureFileExists = true;
dlg.EnsurePathExists = true;
dlg.EnsureReadOnly = false;
dlg.EnsureValidNames = true;
dlg.Multiselect = false;
dlg.ShowPlacesList = true;

if (dlg.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok) 
{
   var folder = dlg.FileName;
   // Do something with selected folder string
}
```

Comment: In my case i have only implrted WindowsAPICodePack-Core and Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell and it works perfectly. Thanks so much.