# Using System.Windows in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1

I have a project in Visual Studio 2019 that I am migrating from .NET Framework 4.6 to .NET Core 3.1.

I used the guide from Microsoft to port my project, [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/).
I ran the [Portability Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) and it showed, that the project is to 100% portable.

But every dependency to System.Windows doesn't work anymore. For example I use `System.Windows.Rect`. In the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.rect?view=netcore-3.1) it clearly states that it is available for .NET Core 3.1.

In the code however it marks Rect with "The type or namespace name 'Rect' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" and on the top it marks my `using System.Windows` grey with the message "Using directive is unnecessary".

This error applies to many things in my code, like `System.Windows.ResourceDictionary`, `System.Windows.Application.Current`, `System.Windows.Point`, ...

So for some reasons it seems that I can't use `System.Windows`, even if the using itself seems to work fine.

I searched for `System.Windows` in the NuGet package manager and [googled it](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22system.windows%22%20in%20.net%20core), but couldn't  find anything.

So here is my question: How can I use `System.Windows` in a .NET Core 3.1 project with Visual Studio 2019? My guess at the moment is, that I need to manually include the assembly `WindowsBase.dll` but in my installation directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional`) I can only find one at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\LiveShare\Agent` and it doesn't seem to be the right one.

Comment: In your .proj file, are you using `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` or `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">` ?

Comment: Did you set `UseWPF=true` property in `csproj` file?

Comment: @RosdiKasim I use the default settings with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I haven't set `UseWPF` in my csproj file, so it is still the default.

Comment: As far as graphics Point and Rect is concerned, Microsoft has released System.Drawing.Common to provide access to GDI+ graphics functionality cross-platform. You can install System.Drawing.Common via NuGet. Check if you have installed that lib.

Comment: Well..., did you try changing it to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` and rebuild?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference System.Windows.Forms in .NET Core 3.0 for WPF apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58844785/how-to-reference-system-windows-forms-in-net-core-3-0-for-wpf-apps)

Answer (score 15):

Here is how to do it with `net5.0`:

```xml
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: The `-windows` is key! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, you would like to use System.Windows.Rect in in a .NET Core 3.1

project with Visual Studio 2019. I find a solution and you can try the following steps.

First, we need to Create a .net core 3.1 console app.

Second, we need to set `UseWPF=true` property in `csproj file`.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
         <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Thirdly, we need install nuget package `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime`.

Fourth, rebuild the app and write the following code.

```
using Windows.Foundation;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rect myRect1 = new Rect();
            myRect1.X = 10;
            myRect1.Y = 100;
            myRect1.Width = 150;
            myRect1.Height = 100;

        }
    }
}
```

Besides, If you want to use `system.windows` in .net core 3.1, I suggest that you use `WPF`

.net core 3.1 app.

Comment: This approach is not recommended by your employer Microsoft. The right one is to create a WPF .NET Core project by running `dotnet new wpf`.